# Automatic driver installation in VS2008 setup project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation, driver

Is there any way how to perform automatic driver installation during my C# app is being installed? I am using standard Setup project in VS2008 (MSI file). My application is communicating with a custom USB device, so the user must install the .NET app first and then manually connect the device to his PC and let Windows install the driver. I would like to make it in one step, without connecting the device to the USB port.

Thanks,
Petr

Answer (score 1):

The best way to go would likely be to pre-install the USB driver. Then, when the USB device is plugged-in, Windows finds and sets up the driver automatically. Here's a place to get started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff549743%28v=vs.85%29.aspx